# imgs get value from data-src

Tags: python, list, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

> File "C:\Users\86134\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\strip-spam.py", line 15, in `<module>`
>
> `print(imgs.get_attribute("data-src"))`
>
> AttributeError: `'list'` object has no attribute `'get_attribute'`.
>
> Did you mean: `'__getattribute__'`?

Above is an error from my code. Can anyone help to fix it?

The `len()` of `imgs` is 60, as the chrome xpath, but `imgs.get_attribute("data-src")` is wrong.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import  time


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

browser.get('https://prediger.de/runde-wandleuchten.html')
print(browser.title)
imgs = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[3]/div[2]/section/article/div/div[1]/div/picture/img')
print(len(imgs))
print(imgs.get_attribute("data-src"))
```

Answer (score 2):

`browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[3]/div[2]/section/article/div/div[1]/div/picture/img')` gives you a **list** of 60 elements.  The `get_attribute` method can be allied on a **single we element**.
So, to make your code working you should iterate over each web element in the list to extract it attribute, as following:

```py
imgs = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[3]/div[2]/section/article/div/div[1]/div/picture/img')
print(len(imgs))
for img in imgs:
    print(img.get_attribute("data-src"))
```

Also, your code is missing a wait. You have to wait for all the elements to loaded before extracting their attributes. The preferred way to do it is with the use of expected conditions explicit waits, as following

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[3]/div[2]/section/article/div/div[1]/div/picture/img')))
#short additional delay to make sure all the elements are loaded after the first element is become visible    
time.sleep(0.5)
#now get the list of images   
imgs = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[3]/div[2]/section/article/div/div[1]/div/picture/img')
print(len(imgs))
for img in imgs:
    print(img.get_attribute("data-src"))
```